# SQL Query to get multiple records with a single different field

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have a table (it's not a table for real but a result of another query) like this:

```
ID | NAME | OPTIONAL_ID | OPTIONAL_NAME | OTHER FIELDS
1  | abc  | 34          | optional 1    | ...
1  | abc  | 35          | optional 2    | ...
1  | abc  | 36          | optional 3    | ...
1  | abc  | 37          | optional 4    | ...
2  | qwe  | 34          | optional 1    | ...
2  | qwe  | 35          | optional 2    | ...
2  | qwe  | 36          | optional 3    | ...
```

What I need is to get a different result with a record for every object, in this example 'abc' and 'qwe' and a Column like OPTIONALS that contains all optional_name for each object.

It's not important for me the output type ( JSON,XML, query output)

I tried with 'group by' but i didn't get the desired result.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: could you show us desired output?

Comment: I guess you want something like `abc | optional 1, optional 2, optional 3, optional 4`, do you?

Comment: A column like that for each object: 
OPTIONALS
optional1,optional2,optional3

or in JSON:
{id:1,Name:'abc',Optionals:['optional1','optional2','optional3','optional4']}
{id:2,Name:'qwe',Optionals:['optional1','optional2','optional3']}

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I considered only relevant columns):

```
declare @table table (name char(3), optional_name char(10))
insert into @table values
('abc', 'optional 1'),
('abc', 'optional 2'),
('abc', 'optional 3'),
('abc', 'optional 4'),
('qwe', 'optional 1'),
('qwe', 'optional 2'),
('qwe', 'optional 3')

select name,
       (select optional_name from @table where name = T.name for xml path(''), type)
from @table [T]
group by name
```

If you want `JSON`, then replace `XML` with `JSON` in last query (newest SQL Server required).

Another option (slightly modified previous query):

```
select name,
       (select optional_name + ', ' from @table where name = T.name for xml path(''), type).value('(/)[1]','varchar(2000)') [optional_name]
from @table [T]
group by name
```

Comment: this query returns to me all records with the optionals column but not in distinct mode and if I add distinct on select SQL get me an error for distinct usage on XML data.

Comment: @GrazianoDimatteo Another solution added, if you would like another way :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `FOR XML` to combine rows for each group:

```
CREATE TABLE #testdata (ID int, NAME varchar(3), OPTIONAL_ID int, OPTIONAL_NAME varchar(10));
INSERT INTO #testdata (ID, NAME, OPTIONAL_ID, OPTIONAL_NAME) VALUES
    (1, 'abc', 34, 'optional 1'),
    (1, 'abc', 35, 'optional 2'),
    (1, 'abc', 36, 'optional 3'),
    (1, 'abc', 37, 'optional 4'),
    (2, 'qwe', 34, 'optional 1'),
    (2, 'qwe', 35, 'optional 2'),
    (2, 'qwe', 36, 'optional 3');

WITH names AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    FROM #testdata
)
SELECT *
FROM names
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT OPTIONAL_NAME
    FROM #testdata
    WHERE names.NAME = #testdata.NAME
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('OPTIONAL_NAMES'), TYPE
) AS ca(xmldata)
```

[image: Query Result]

For comma separated list inside query output, use:

```
SELECT names.NAME, STUFF(xmldata, 1, 1, '')
FROM names
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ',' + OPTIONAL_NAME
    FROM #testdata
    WHERE names.NAME = #testdata.NAME
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS ca(xmldata)
```

Answer (score 0):

An XML Solution can look something like....

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT , NAME VARCHAR(20), OPTIONAL_ID INT 
                    ,  OPTIONAL_NAME VARCHAR(20), OTHER_FIELDS VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES 
(1  ,'abc'  , 34  ,'optional 1' , 'Some Data' ),
(1  ,'abc'  , 35  ,'optional 2' , 'Some Data' ),
(1  ,'abc'  , 36  ,'optional 3' , 'Some Data' ),
(1  ,'abc'  , 37  ,'optional 4' , 'Some Data' ),
(2  ,'qwe'  , 34  ,'optional 1' , 'Some Data' ),
(2  ,'qwe'  , 35  ,'optional 2' , 'Some Data' ),
(2  ,'qwe'  , 36  ,'optional 3' , 'Some Data' );
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
           t.[ID] AS [@ID]
        ,  t.Name AS [@Name]
        , (  
            SELECT  t2.OPTIONAL_ID
                  , t2.OPTIONAL_NAME
                  , t2.OTHER_FIELDS
            FROM #temp t2
            WHERE t.ID = t2.ID
            FOR XML PATH('OPTIONALS') , TYPE
           )
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [ID] , Name
    FROM #temp 
)t
FOR XML PATH('x')
```

**XML OUTPUT**

```
<x ID="1" Name="abc">
  <OPTIONALS>
    <OPTIONAL_ID>34</OPTIONAL_ID>
    <OPTIONAL_NAME>optional 1</OPTIONAL_NAME>
    <OTHER_FIELDS>Some Data</OTHER_FIELDS>
  </OPTIONALS>
  <OPTIONALS>
    <OPTIONAL_ID>35</OPTIONAL_ID>
    <OPTIONAL_NAME>optional 2</OPTIONAL_NAME>
    <OTHER_FIELDS>Some Data</OTHER_FIELDS>
  </OPTIONALS>
  <OPTIONALS>
    <OPTIONAL_ID>36</OPTIONAL_ID>
    <OPTIONAL_NAME>optional 3</OPTIONAL_NAME>
    <OTHER_FIELDS>Some Data</OTHER_FIELDS>
  </OPTIONALS>
  <OPTIONALS>
    <OPTIONAL_ID>37</OPTIONAL_ID>
    <OPTIONAL_NAME>optional 4</OPTIONAL_NAME>
    <OTHER_FIELDS>Some Data</OTHER_FIELDS>
  </OPTIONALS>
</x>
<x ID="2" Name="qwe">
  <OPTIONALS>
    <OPTIONAL_ID>34</OPTIONAL_ID>
    <OPTIONAL_NAME>optional 1</OPTIONAL_NAME>
    <OTHER_FIELDS>Some Data</OTHER_FIELDS>
  </OPTIONALS>
  <OPTIONALS>
    <OPTIONAL_ID>35</OPTIONAL_ID>
    <OPTIONAL_NAME>optional 2</OPTIONAL_NAME>
    <OTHER_FIELDS>Some Data</OTHER_FIELDS>
  </OPTIONALS>
  <OPTIONALS>
    <OPTIONAL_ID>36</OPTIONAL_ID>
    <OPTIONAL_NAME>optional 3</OPTIONAL_NAME>
    <OTHER_FIELDS>Some Data</OTHER_FIELDS>
  </OPTIONALS>
</x>
```

Comment: why this query returns to me only the first element?